# When I center Navbar the text becomes squished

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I would like my navbar to be centered and always be shown at the top of the screen however whenever i think I've fixed it something goes wrong this time the text text is mushed. I would like it to be strait across. Also sometimes when I try to fix it the "Home" button and the image overlap. Thank You.

[How it looks centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhUwX.png)

[How I would like it to look, but not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfpke.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>The Benjamin Project | Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/assets/img/favicon.ico"> <!-- site icon -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/assets/script.js"></script>

    <style>

    @font-face {
      font-family: Panton;
      src:url("/static/assets/font/Panton-LightCaps.otf");
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #8CD28C;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      min-height:75px;
      line-height:75px;
    }
    .navbar {
      margin: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      background-color: #8CD28C; /*bg color for tabs on navbar*/
      color: #606060; /*text color for tabs on navbar*/
      padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
      font-size: 2em;
      font-family:Panton;
      border: 0;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a:hover {
      color: #606060; /*text color for active*/
      background-color: #8CD28C; /*bg color for active*/
      font-weight: bold;


    }
    .selected {
     text-decoration-line:underline;


    }
    .navbar .navbar-brand img {
      border-radius: 360%; /*rounds image*/
      margin-top: -55px;
      margin-right: 10px;

    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
      color: #606060; /*non active colors*/
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
      color: #606060; /*color of text being hovered over*/
      background-color: inherit;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .row {
       margin-top: 3%;
       padding-left: 20%;
       padding-right: 20%;
       animation-duration: 2s;
        }
    .row hr {
      display: block;
      height: 1px;
      border: 0;
      border-top: 2px solid #606060;
      border-radius: 100%;
      margin: 1em 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .center{
      width:50%;
      max-width:960px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }

  </style>
</head>




  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default fadeInDown animated navbar-static-top center">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <!-- navigation button on mobile -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://imgur.com/k8SlOAa.png" allign="middle" width="125" height="125"></a> <!-- benjamin logo  alt="Benjamin Logo"-->
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left center" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active selected"><a href="/">Home</a></li> <!-- labels on navigation bar -->
            <li><a href="/commands">Commands & Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/home/views/benjamins.html">Benjamins</a></li>
            <li><a href="/account/login">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

  </nav>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/script.js"></script>

  <page class="main">

  <div class="row fadeIn animated"><hr></div>

  </page>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider removing the class `center` from `.navbar-collapse`, looks like you don't need it (you already have it declared to a containing element, it's inheriting the `width` property of `50%`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue with making the `nav` look like your linked image was

```
.center{
  width:50%;
  max-width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here it works fine if removed. You can expand to look at full screen or see it here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpZGwZ.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #8CD28C !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #8CD28C !important;
  /*bg color for tabs on navbar*/
  color: #606060;
  /*text color for tabs on navbar*/
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Panton;
  border: 0 !important;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a:hover {
  color: #606060;
  /*text color for active*/
  background-color: #8CD28C;
  /*bg color for active*/
  font-weight: bold;
}

.selected {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand img {
  border-radius: 360%;
  margin-top: -55px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #606060;
  /*non active colors*/
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #606060;
  /*color of text being hovered over*/
  background-color: inherit;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.page-padding {
  padding: 0 10%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .page-padding {
    padding: 0 13%;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #606060;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
}

.page-content hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #606060;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>
<body>
  <div class="page-padding">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/k8SlOAa.png" width="125" height="125"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active selected"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/commands">Commands & Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/home/views/benjamins.html">Benjamins</a></li>
          <li><a href="/account/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </nav>

    <page class="main">
      <div class="page-content fadeIn animated">
        <hr>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac felis facilisis, pellentesque mauris at, accumsan diam. Ut aliquet eros a quam consequat bibendum. Donec lacinia odio aliquet, rutrum magna sit amet, mollis tortor. Nunc in viverra
          libero. Phasellus eget tellus eget lorem mollis sodales. Fusce sem eros, molestie eu turpis sed, tempus finibus ipsum. Donec consectetur lectus ac dui gravida, nec tristique eros semper. Proin in vestibulum eros, ut ullamcorper purus. Proin
          tincidunt neque urna, non placerat mi tincidunt id. Nulla eros tellus, feugiat tincidunt ex quis, laoreet interdum elit. Morbi dapibus, lacus id viverra posuere, arcu nulla aliquet mi, eu sollicitudin quam massa sed justo. Suspendisse vel lobortis
          nibh, non convallis quam.</p>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </page>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't get that from your images. Give me a moment and I'll update things.

Comment: Thank You but do you know how i could center the image and Text so it's directly above the <hr> break? I added `width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;` to .navbar but it made it look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/Zg1dm)

Comment: It is due to breakpoints of `@media` queries. Because you are setting the padding of `row` at 20% you'll be losing 40% of the screen across any device, or now setting the width to 50% means a once screen width that the left and right elements touch, the menu will drop below.

Comment: UPDATED: The only way to keep as close to your requirements as possible was to reduce page margins and remove your changes to the `row`. Added`@media` query to reduce the font size of header menu too. Only other way to do this would be to drop the menu below 992px.